# Invisible components and events

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air, flex4

I have Flex 4 application in which I have one component as top layer which displays something like tooltips, basically user sees "presentation" which explains usage and meaning of the tools "below", sliders, checkboxes, text fields etc. 
I made this "presentation" using sequences so first tooltip is visible, then becomes invisible, second is visible etc.

I tried to disable mouseChildren, mouseEnabled and other possible parameters which would disable those tooltips from preventing user clicking on some button or checkbox.

Obviously those components which render tooltips even tough invisible, are still "clickable".

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, answered my own question, here's the secret:

```
<s:SetAction property="includeInLayout" startDelay="0" value="false"/>
<s:SetAction property="includeInLayout" startDelay="30000" value="true"/>
```